# Need to use form_tag, but the page is rendered through active_scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

The main page is processed and given by active_scaffold. In that case I can't find a place to use form_tag (to make a form_tag in order to pass a FILE object to a controller).

I did go through the wiki page about active_scaffold, and had not figured out a way to replace form_tag..

Really need some help

Answer (score 0):

```
p params[:record][:excel].original_filename
```

that works out !